In Umbraco 13, how do I implement ReCaptcha v3 without using Umbraco Forms?
I have a login and registration page on my Umbraco 13 site, implemented as per the instructions in the Umbraco CMS v13 documentation "members registration and login" page.
I want to add ReCaptcha to it (v3 ideally).
Having searched the documentation for Umbraco 13, I can only find mentions of ReCaptcha for Umbraco Forms.  They explain how you are supposed to have a Document Type with a property of Data Type "ReCaptcha v3 with Score".
I followed the instructions for this - creating the ReCaptcha SiteKey and PrivateKey at the Google Developers site. I put them in my User Secrets file for my localhost site, and I then restarted my application.
I can only see the following that are available:

My login page is using the Umbraco 13 snippet looking like the following:
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<UmbLoginController>(
    "HandleLogin", new { RedirectUrl = loginModel.RedirectUrl })) {

        <h4>Log in with a local account.</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="@loginModel.Username" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@loginModel.Username" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@loginModel.Username" class="form-text text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="@loginModel.Password" class="form-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@loginModel.Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@loginModel.Password" class="form-text text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 form-check">
            <input asp-for="@loginModel.RememberMe" class="form-check-input">
            <label asp-for="@loginModel.RememberMe" class="form-check-label">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => loginModel.RememberMe)
            </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
    }

Questions:

Why does the Data Type ReCatpcha v3 not appear available for any of my Data Types?
How do I insert a ReCaptcha prompt into my Macro?
Can someone explain how I could do this login using Umbraco Forms?
Can you please clarify the difference between rendering Umbraco Forms and rendering a Macro with a login form?
When does an MVC form become a Umbraco Forms form?

Sincerest thanks for taking the time to read this question.

You have to create your own controller for login instead of the UmbLoginController provided by Umbraco. Then you have to manually implement the Recaptcha as per their documentation. That includes both client and server-side validations.
